# How is the buffer thats used in fread()/fwrite different from the one used in read()/write()?

Tags: unix

The syntax of fread() is

```
size_t fread(void *buf,size_t size, size_t, count, FILE *stream);
```

whereas for read() it is

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t len);
```

Both of them uses buffer to put the read data. How are these two different? 
My question arises from the term 'Buffered I/O used for fread()/fwrite() stdio calls and not for the system calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fread` can have its own buffer, whereas `read` has no buffer other than the one you supply to it. So, `read` is unbuffered: you're just supplying a memory location into which the read can happen, but the stdio functions are (generally) buffered for you.

For example, an `fgets` won't read byte-by-byte (because that's inefficient). Instead, it will read in chunks, and sometimes might read in too much, beyond a newline. Then, there'll be some data waiting in the read buffer that an `fread` might return immediately without a syscall.

Comment: Wait, `read` is not buffered? The man page doesn't talk about it. How do you know that? (And why is it so hard to search that on google?!)

Comment: OK, not buffered with respect to the user-land view of the fd. The fd is an abstraction (like a tap, or faucet to Americans?), and the tap is the boundary between the kernel and your code. `read(2)` is unbuffered in the sense that anything that comes out is data that's being freshly transferred into your process: to the application, that data has only just sprung into existence (for all we know, the network card handles TCP onboard and does DMA right into the application's RAM). As an implementation detail, the kernel probably has a buffer too, but conceptually `read` is truly unbuffered.

Comment: Also, how did I know that? Because that's how fds work. Also just to point out, some calls to `read` are definitely not buffered: special device nodes and /proc for example can have the read fulfilled immediately. Whether or not the kernel has its own buffer for an fd's reads is not something you can find out in your application.